# Spring boot 1.3.3 is not building with gradle 3.0

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Thought of sharing below info as i spent couple of hours finding this:

Spring boot 1.3.3 project is not building with gradle 3 as spring boot gradle plugin is built for gradle 2. Hence, build this project only with gradle 2 but not with gradle 3.

```
$ gradle build
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_2yz3q0eod1vuhee49o6tow8db.run(C:\Users\nm_su\Projects\provisioning\mobipm\build.gradle:23)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\nm_su\Projects\provisioning\mobipm\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mobipm'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']
   > Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.67 secs

$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-11-22 15:19:54 UTC
Revision:     83b485b914fd4f335ad0e66af9d14aad458d2cc5

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Now lets try building with gradle 2.14.1,

```
$ gradle build
:framework:compileJava
:framework:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:framework:classes
:framework:jar
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build
:framework:findMainClass
:framework:bootRepackage
:framework:assemble
:framework:compileTestJava
:framework:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:framework:testClasses
:framework:test
:framework:check
:framework:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 31.104 secs

$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.14.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-07-18 06:38:37 UTC
Revision:     d9e2113d9fb05a5caabba61798bdb8dfdca83719

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

If you are using eclipse plugin "Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0", then while importing the Spring boot 1.3.3 project, explicitly select the olderversion of gradle as below

[image]

Comment: I had similar issue. Download gradle zip from gradle site and use local installation directory as work around for this.

Comment: You should use the Gradle wrapper in any Gradle built project and be it the tiniest. Then the build always works correctly as designed, because the wrapper will run the build with the exact version of Gradle the build is designed for and tested with and the only thing you need to run the build is a compatible installed Java, no Gradle installation is necessary. You can even bootstrap new Gradle projects with the wrapper of another Gradle project without having Gradle installed locally manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the build.gradle has the "wrapper" task as below:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Run the "gradle wrapper" from the command line, it would create the gradle wrappers for unix and windows. Push them to source control so that,there are no manual steps.

```
gradle wrapper
git add gradlew gradlew.bat gradle
git commit -m "Adding gradle wrapper to git repo"
git push
```

So all the future builds can be using gradlew

```
$ ./gradlew build
:framework:compileJava
:framework:processResources
:framework:classes
:framework:jar
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build
:framework:findMainClass
:framework:bootRepackage
:framework:assemble
:framework:compileTestJava
:framework:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:framework:testClasses
:framework:test
:framework:check
:framework:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 42.712 secs
```

Thanks to answer from Vampire...