# Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, plugins, dependencies

I am working on a project and I tried to run the gradle wrapper but the build failed and I got the following error:

```
:gulpConstantDev FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task :gulpConstantDev.
 gulp not installed in node_modules, please first run gradle installGulp
```

I then ran `grade installGulp`, but the build failed again and I got the following error:

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gateway'.
 Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']
    Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.
```

I am a novice programmer and I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is your gradle version ?

Comment: Seems like this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675234/spring-boot-1-3-3-is-not-building-with-gradle-3-0

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a little bit late. I was facing the same issue tonight. I solved it by adding as a dependency "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin".
For exemple I have:

```
  ext {
        spring_version = "4.2.5.RELEASE"
        springboot_version = "1.3.3.RELEASE"
        spring_dependency_management_version = "0.6.1.RELEASE"
    }
```

And

```
 dependencies {
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${spring_dependency_management_version}")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springboot_version}")
    }
```

I hope that could help.

Comment: Not so offtopic: I was getting the OP's error in a project I have at work and have little experience with Gradle. @Novy 's solution really solved. Turns out I found that I may have upgraded my IntelliJ to the newest one, which supports Gradle 3.0+ natively, although my working project is configured to Gradle 2.7. So, mind your repo Gradle version.